# Can you remove a clause from the query builder?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Looking at the [API for Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html) it seems that all parts of the query are kept in properties like `$joins, $wheres, $groups` etc.
I also see those properties are public.

My use case is for example scopes, let's say (pure fiction)

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function scopeIsSmart($query)
    {
        return $query->join('tests', 'users.id', '=', 'tests.user')
            ->where('tests.score', '>', 130);
    }

    public function scopeIsMathGuy($query)
    {
        return $query->join('tests', 'users.id', '=', 'tests.user')
           ->where('tests.type', '=', 'math');
    }    
}
```

If I now write

```
User::query()->isSmart()->isMathGuy()->get();
```

I will get an error for joining the same table 2 times. What is a good way to make the joins array unique? (no duplicate joins)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for existing JOINs:

```php
public function scopeIsMathGuy($query)
{
    if (collect($query->getQuery()->joins)->where('table', 'tests')->isEmpty()) {
        $query->join('tests', 'users.id', '=', 'tests.user');
    }
    $query->where('tests.type', '=', 'math');
}
```

You can also create a helper like `joinOnce()` (see this [PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/24752)).

Comment: a shame Taylor rejected the PR.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = Test::query();
   if ($request['is_smart']) {
      $query->where('score', '>', 130);
   }

   if ($request['is_math']) {
      $query->where('type', 'math');
   }
$result = $query->with('users')->all();
$users = $result->get('users');
```

Comment: The problem is that relationships (`with()`) do not change the resultset of `User`. That's why I'm asking to do it on the Query Builder and not with a relationship

Comment: Yes that is a possible solution for my example. I made it too simple. But if we have a query consisting of 4 tables (3 joins) with each their scopes this still won't work. So really thank you, but your solution is a workaround trying to change the table with the most `where` clauses as the  `from`.